# Snakemake: 'Missing input files' due to wrong wildcard expansion

Tags: snakemake

I am new to Snakemake and I want to write a very simple Snakefile with a rule that processes each input file separately to an output file, but somehow my wildcards aren't interpreted correctly.

I have set up a minimal, reproducible example environment in Ubuntu 18.04 with the input files "test/test1.txt", "test/test2.txt", and a Snakefile. (snakemake version 5.5.4)

Snakefile:

```
ins = glob_wildcards("test/{f}.txt")

rule all:
  input: expand("out/{f}.txt", f=ins)

rule test:
  input: "test/{f}.txt"
  output: "out/{f}.txt"
  shell: "touch {output}"
```

This Snakefile throws the following error while building the DAG of jobs:

```
Missing input files for rule test:
test/['test1', 'test2'].txt
```

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to use `ins.f` or something similar:

```
expand("out/{f}.txt", f= ins.f)
```

The reason is explained in the [FAQ](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#how-do-i-run-my-rule-on-all-files-of-a-certain-directory)

> [glob_wildcards returns] a named tuple that contains a list of values
>   for each wildcard.

Comment: Thank you much! It was indeed `ins.f` to resolve the problem.

Comment: You can also do 'ins, = glob_wildcards("test/{f}.txt")' (note the comma). The snakemake documentation shows this method.